# How to access parent class variable having same name as child variable with child reference outside the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

Is there a way to access parent class instance variable with the same name as another child class instance variable through child reference outside child class?

```
class Parent {
    int i;
}
class Child extends Parent {
    int i=10;

}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p=new Parent();
        Child c=new Child();
        System.out.println(p.i);//parent i variable
        System.out.println(c.i);//child i variable
        System.out.println(c.i);// again child i variable
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need this way?

Comment: Also, does this code work? Because you didn't actually say anything about getting errors, yet there's a code... I'm assuming you just wrote the code here in the question, and are asking us if this works?

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra the code works. I wanted to know if there is any way we can call instance variable i of parent class through child class reference outside child class.

Comment: @Deadpool. Just wanted to know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson c.super.i is giving compile time error

Comment: c.super.i doesn't compile guys, please check before adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `Child` to `Parent`:

```
System.out.println(((Parent) c).i);
```

Why does it work?

A `Child` instance has two fields named `i`, one from the `Parent` class and one from `Child`, and the compiler (not the runtime type of the instance) decides which one gets used. The compiler does this based on the type he sees. So, if the compiler knows it's a `Child` instance, he'll produce an accessor for the `Child` field. If he only knows it's a `Parent`, you get access to the `Parent` field.

Some examples:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
Parent childAsParent = child;

System.out.println(parent.i);             // parent value
System.out.println(child.i);              // child value
System.out.println(((Parent) child) .i);  // parent value by inline cast
System.out.println(childAsParent.i);      // parent value by broader variable type
```

If the compiler knows it's a `Child`, he gives access to the `Child` field, if you take this knowledge away (by casting or by storing into a `Parent` variable), you get access to the `Parent` field.

**This is confusing, isn't it?** It's an invitation for all kinds of nasty misunderstandings and coding mistakes. So it's good advice not to have the same field name in a parent and a child class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a good reason for it, then yes:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    int i=10;

    public int getParentsI() {
       return super.i;
    }
}
```

Now your main method will look like:

```
Parent p=new Parent();
Child c=new Child();
System.out.println(p.i);//parent i variable
System.out.println(c.i);//child i variable
System.out.println(c.getParentsI());// parent i variable
```

Edit: realized the user may be new so I'll fully flesh out the method sig and comment more

Comment: Indentation please.

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot to mention, is there a way to do it without using a method in child class
I am sorry i am very new to the site, this question might be silly, but it just came through my mind while reading about use of super keyword
Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do it without using a child class method